# How do i reference the currentPage title property in a custom component's js file?

Tags: javascript, aem

I'm making a semi-custom list component in AEM that acts like a sidebar nav. I want to add an active class to a list item depending on if it is the link to the current page. I know how to reference `currentPage.title` in html and `currentPage.getTitle()` in JSP.

Am I missing an easy way to reference the `currentPage` title property in the component's separate clientlibs js file?

Not every page has a title tag or strict html elements to reference, so I'd like to use the aem properties before I go down that route.

Comment: I'd prefer a front-end solution over a backend one, take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url/. but if you want to go the server-side route, yes using page path or title works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clientlibs contains js code that is executed on browser, so you cannot access objects like currentPage that are only available on server during jsp/htl execution.

One way to achieve that would be to put those values in html element attributes in your HTL and later access them in js.

e.g. in sightly-

```
<div id="titleHolder" data-page-title="${currentPage.title}">
```

and to access it in js-

```
var pageTitle = $("#titleHolder").data("page-title");
```

You can also put these in a JavaScript object instead of dom element attributes.